# Php Price calculation based on given table

Tags: php, matrix

using this price table we are calculating price of the given input measurement

[image]

example:

```
(1) width = 30; , height =56 ; Price=? 

 so 
 (width>25){ new_width=50; }
 (height<100){ new_height=100; }

    so price = 20;


(2) width =12; height=267;

    (width<25){ new_width=25; }
    (height>250){ new_height=300; }

    so price= 30;
```

I wrote a function for to calculate price based on the given value, and this function help to get the `new_width` , and `height` based on the table , But I don't know how to get price based on this table.

```
function calculate_price($width,$height ){

        if($width<25){
             $new_width=25;
          }elseif($width>25 && $width<50 ){
             $new_width=50;
          }else{
            $new_width=50;
          }  


        if($width<100){
             $new_width=100;
          }elseif($width>100 && $width<150 ){
             $new_width=150;
          }elseif($width>150 && $width<200 ){
             $new_width=200;
          }elseif($width>200 && $width<250 ){
             $new_width=250;
          }elseif($width>250 && $width<300 ){
             $new_width=300;
          }
          else{
            $new_width=300;
          }


        $price=needed forumula [ based on new_width & new_height ];

      return $price ;



    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ceil` to round up the width and height  this function

You can use array to store the price with key `height_width` for simplicity.

```
function calculate_price($width, $height) {
    $price = array(
        "100_25" => 10,
        "100_50" => 20,
        "150_25" => 15,
        "150_50" => 25,
        "200_25" => 18,
        "200_50" => 31,
        "250_25" => 24,
        "250_50" => 42,
        "300_25" => 20,
        "300_50" => 45,
    );

    $newWidth = ceil($width / 25) * 25; //Round up by 25
    $newHeight = ceil($height / 50) * 50; //Round up by 50

    return $price[ $newHeight . "_" . $newWidth ];
}
```

You can call

```
echo calculate_price( 30, 56 ); /* width and height parameters */
```

This will result to

```
20
```

Comment: I'm just curious, why didn't you go for a 2D array instead of using an underscore in the key?

Comment: @WilliamPerron I mean we can use 2D array, but i find this way simplistic for beginners.

Comment: thanks friend for this solution . But my problem is my excel list is large , if i writ program this way there will be many lines

Comment: Is there any logic on the pricing? a formula? @abilasher

Comment: actually there is no logic in pricing , and this is given by client . But the thing is that there is a logic in width , height cutoff . one level to second level height increase by 50 and width increase by 25.

Comment: If you dont have a logic or formula for pricing, you need to put it on db or an array like above

Comment: The logic for width and height is already solved with my answer above @abilasher

Answer (score 1):

Base on the info you provided, you have two logical paths. The first, is the width less than or equal to 25 or is the width greater then 25. Then you have to reason out the height.

Consider the following:

```
function calculate_price($width, $height){
  $price = false;
  if($width > 25){
    switch(true){
      case $height <= 100:
        $price = 20;
        break;
      case $height <= 150:
        $price = 25;
        break;
      case $height <= 200:
        $price = 31;
        break;
      case $height <= 250:
        $price = 42;
        break;
      case $height <= 300:
        $price = 45;
        break;
    }
  } else {
    switch(true){
      case $height <= 100:
        $price = 10;
        break;
      case $height <= 150:
        $price = 15;
        break;
      case $height <= 200:
        $price = 18;
        break;
      case $height <= 250:
        $price = 24;
        break;
      case $height <= 300:
        $price = 30;
        break;
    }
  }
  return $price;
}
```

With the following input: `echo calculate_price(30, 56);` we would have an output of: `20`.

Running the following:

```
echo calculate_price(30, 56) . "<br />";
echo calculate_price(12, 267) . "<br />";
echo calculate_price(25, 249) . "<br />";
```

I get:

```
20
30
24
```

Format as needed (E.G.: `echo sprintf("$%d.00", calculate_price(30, 56));`)

**Full Test**

```
<?php
function calculate_price($width, $height){
    $price = false;
    if(!is_int($width) || !is_int($height)){
        return $price;
    }
    if($width > 25){
        switch(true){
            case $height <= 100:
            $price = 20;
            break;
            case $height <= 150:
            $price = 25;
            break;
            case $height <= 200:
            $price = 31;
            break;
            case $height <= 250:
            $price = 42;
            break;
            case $height <= 300:
            $price = 45;
            break;
        }
    } else {
        switch(true){
            case $height <= 100:
            $price = 10;
            break;
            case $height <= 150:
            $price = 15;
            break;
            case $height <= 200:
            $price = 18;
            break;
            case $height <= 250:
            $price = 24;
            break;
            case $height <= 300:
            $price = 30;
            break;
        }
    }
    return $price;
}

echo sprintf("$%d.00", calculate_price(30, 56)) . "<br />";
echo sprintf("$%d.00", calculate_price(12, 267)) . "<br />";
echo sprintf("$%d.00", calculate_price(25, 249)) . "<br />";
echo sprintf("$%d.00", calculate_price(-1, 'a')) . "<br />";
?>
```

Results:

```
$20.00
$30.00
$24.00
$0.00
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Multidimensional Array

```
$x = "300";
$y = "50";

$multi  = array();

$multi["100"]["25"] = "10";
$multi["100"]["50"] =  "20";
$multi["200"]["25"] = "30";
$multi["300"]["50"] =  "40";    

echo $multi[$x][$y];
```

Answer (score 0):

Based of your code, if you don't have database to get those $price, I think you can try somehting like this :

```
function calculate_price($width,$height ){
    // Your $new_width according to your $width
    if($width<=25){
        $new_width=25;
    }else
        $new_width=50;
    }  

    // Your $new_height according to your $height
    if($height<=100){
        $new_height=100;
    }elseif($height>100 && $height<=150 ){
        $new_height=150;
    }elseif($height>150 && $height<=200 ){
        $new_height=200;
    }elseif($height>200 && $height<=250 ){
        $new_height=250;
    }elseif($height>250){
        $new_height=300;
    }

    // Now, according to your new value you will find the price with some test :
    if ($new_width == 25) {
        switch($new_height) {
            case 100 : $price = 10; break;
            case 150 : $price = 15; break;
            case 200 : $price = 18; break;
            case 250 : $price = 24; break;
            case 300 : $price = 30; break;
        }
    } else {
        switch($new_height) {
            case 100 : $price = 20; break;
            case 150 : $price = 25; break;
            case 200 : $price = 31; break;
            case 250 : $price = 42; break;
            case 300 : $price = 45; break;
        }
    }

  return $price ;
}
```

But I think you can find other way to achieve it too as suggested in other anwser !

Is this what you are looking for? It's not very flexible since you don't use database to get those value but it should work